# Subset closed under vector addition and subtraction, but not scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This will seem like a textbook problem, yes It is! . but really, I am not getting any clue.

Construct a subset of the $x$-$y$ plane $\mathbb {R^2}$ that is
closed under vector addition and subtraction, but not scalar multiplication.

I was not able to make a generalized subset.
please, briefly write how to approach Such type of problems, as they are very prevalent in Abstract vector spaces and Group Theory.

Comment: Perhaps $\Bbb Z^2$? The integers form a ring, so this is obviously closed under addition. However, it's not closed under multiplication from scalars in $\Bbb R$: for instance, $\pi(1,1) \not \in \Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: By scalars, you mean real scalars? I don't know, take the integers, rationals, any discrete subgroup under addition.

Comment: If you have a vector $v$ in your subset, then it must also contain $v+v=2v$, as well as $3v,4v,\cdots$ and through subtraction also $0,-v,-2v,\cdots$. In other words, it must contain $\{nv\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Observe such a set is itself closed under addition/subtraction. It is also obviously closed under multiplication by *integers*, but what about arbitrary real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Take example as $\mathbb{Q}^2 $ , which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 $ ,

For any two, $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 $
$(x_1,y_1) \pm (x_2,y_2) = (x_1\pm x_2,y_1\pm y_2) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 $

( as , $\mathbb{Q} $ is closed under addition and subtraction)

But for scalar multiplication over $\mathbb{R} $  i.e, with reals,
For any real $c$,  $ c (x,y) = (cx , cy ) $ need not to be always in $\mathbb{Q}^2 $ ( as, multiplication of irrational and non zero rational numbers always be irrational number)

As this you can creat more subsets like this . ( Like, $\mathbb{Z}^2 , 
\mathbb{Q} × \{0\} , \mathbb{Z} × \{0\} $  etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider all lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $V := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$. Firstly, $V$ is a vector space. Since addition (and subtraction) of integers is closed, but the multiplication of an integer by any real number need not be an integer.

Comment: V is not a vector space. Vector spaces must be closed under scalar multiplication. That is an example of a subset that satisfies element wise addition but not scalar multiplication that is a subset of $R^2$